# How to call AutoIt script from protractor test

Tags: automation, jasmine, protractor, autoit

I want to save one file to my machine, while automating a scenario using protractor. I have created an autoIt script, but no idea on how we can call the script in protractor.

Using Protractor with jasmine

Comment: you can try npm package: `shelljs`, or nodejs buildin module `childProcess`

Answer (score 1):

1) Build your AutoIt script into  an .exe file.

2) Put the EXE file as a part of your project source code

3) Following below code example to execute the EXE by `shelljs`

```
var shell = require('shelljs');

// relative file path for the autoit exe
var cmd = './autoit/xxx.exe';
var task = shell.exec(cmd);

if (task.code !== 0) {
    shell.echo("execute AutoIt script fail: " + task.stdout);
    shell.exit(1);
}
```